# Regular expression find word but NOT if it's part of a larger phrase

Tags: python, string

What I am looking for is a way to find a keyword in a set of text, *then* check if that text is a part of a larger phrase. Here's a few examples to illustrate what I mean.

Let's say I'm looking for text that contains the word electric. But I'm NOT looking for general electric. So if the text is:

> The atmosphere is **electric**!

I would like it to return a positive. But if instead it is:

> I just got a new job at general **electric**!

I *don't* want that to show up. Now normally I would do this using a regular expression for (electric), then doing another regular expression search for **general electric** if found, return a negative.

HOWEVEVER, this type of text spoils that plan.

> I'm at a party for general electric. The atmosphere here is electric!

Because this has an instance of the word electric that is *not* a part of the larger string, I want it to return a positive. BUT, doing a re search for general electric would make it seem like I should return a negative using my method.

What type of algorithm can I use to solve these issues in Python?

Comment: given this limited example, one way to check is to split up the sentence and if the preceding word is a noun/verb, then either exclude/include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *lookaround*.

```
import re

re.search(r'(?<!general )\belectric\b', 'The atmosphere is electric!')
# <re.Match object; span=(18, 26), match='electric'>

re.search(r'(?<!general )\belectric\b', 'I just got a new job at general electric!')
# None

re.search(r'(?<!general )\belectric\b', 'I\'m at a party for general electric. The atmosphere here is electric!')
# <re.Match object; span=(60, 68), match='electric'>
```

`(?<!  ...  )` is negative lookbehind. `(?<!general )\belectric\b` means `general`  cannot come before word `electric`. This regex will only match `electric` that does not have `general`  before that.

You can learn more about lookaround at [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)